# Lost Git bundle in Textmate?

Tags: git, textmate

I'm not sure what happened here but I seem to have lost the git bundle in Textmate? I thought I might have accidentally removed it, but when I reinstall it, it still doesn't show up in my bundle list?

Anyone know how I can get git back? ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maintained on Github at https://github.com/jcf/git-tmbundle

Either `git clone` the repo or download an archive from [the downloads page](https://github.com/jcf/git-tmbundle/downloads).